# Get size of subdirectories and write in file powershell windows

Tags: powershell

I have a mounted directory Z:\ and it has a directory called `Main` under it there are many subdirectories, I want to know the size of each of these direct subdirectories (not sub-subdirectories) and write it in file. So for example if `Main` has 3 subdirectories `A` ,`B`, `C` then I want in the text file to look like this

```
Z:\Main\A 153MB
Z:\Main\B 2.3GB
Z:\Main\C 1.2TB
```

and so on. Any advice how this can be done in powershell?

Comment: `$sum=0;gci Z:\Main\A -recurse|select-object Length|%{$sum += $_.Length}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$array= @() 
$folder = "Z:\Main" 
Get-ChildItem $folder -Recurse -Depth 0 | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | 
ForEach-Object { 
    $obj = New-Object PSObject

    $Size = [Math]::Round((Get-ChildItem -Recurse $_.FullName | Measure-Object Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum / 1KB, 2) 
    $obj |Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Path" $_.Name 
    $obj |Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SizeMB" $Size 
    $array +=$obj 
}

$array | select Path,SizeMB |  Export-Csv $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\OutputFile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: FYI - In Powershell 3+, you can use `Get-ChildItem -Directory` instead of `Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer }`

Answer (score 0):

I was about to suggest :

```
$path = 'C:\Program Files'
$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Directory -Recurse

foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Location = $Folder.fullname
        Size = [math]::Round(((Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder.fullname -File | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum / 1MB),2)

    }
}
```

Addig items to an array in a loop is not good idea, as arrays are static. 
Each and every time an item is being added, array is copied into the memory, destroyed, and re-created with the new item ... which is very expensive process and should be avoided, where possible!!

Answer (score 0):

this was done for a friend a while ago ... it defaults to getting the full subdirectory tree size. however, the `-NoRecurse` switch parameter will make it give just the size of each subdir without anything deeper.

```
function Get-SubDirSize
    {
    [CmdletBinding ()]
    Param (
        [Parameter (
            Position = 0
            )]
            [string]
            $Path = $env:TEMP,

        [Parameter ()]
            [switch]
            $NoRecurse
        )

    begin {}

    process
        {
        $DirList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Path -Directory

        foreach ($DL_Item in $DirList)
            {
            $GCI_Params = @{
                LiteralPath = $DL_Item.FullName
                Recurse = -not $NoRecurse
                File = $True
                Force = $True
                ErrorAction = 'SilentlyContinue'
                }
            $FileList = Get-ChildItem @GCI_Params
            if ($FileList.Count -gt 0)
                {
                $DirSize = [math]::Round(($FileList |
                    Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum / 1MB, 2)
                }
                else
                {
                $DirSize = 0
                }

            [PSCustomObject]@{
                DirName = $DL_Item.FullName
                FileCount = $FileList.Count
                Size_MB = $DirSize
                }
            }
        }

    end {}

    } # end >>> function Get-SubDirSize
```

called thus ...

```
Get-SubDirSize -Path $env:ProgramData -NoRecurse
```

... it gives the following ...

```
DirName                                 FileCount Size_MB
-------                                 --------- -------
C:\ProgramData\Apple                            0       0
C:\ProgramData\Apple Computer                   0       0
C:\ProgramData\AVAST Software                   0       0
C:\ProgramData\Binary Fortress Software         0       0
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey                       5    6.48
C:\ProgramData\Git                              1       0
C:\ProgramData\IsolatedStorage                  0       0
C:\ProgramData\Last.fm                          0       0
C:\ProgramData\LogiShrd                         1       0
C:\ProgramData\Malwarebytes                     0       0
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft                        0       0
C:\ProgramData\MindGems                         0       0
C:\ProgramData\Mozilla                          0       0
C:\ProgramData\NCH Software                     0       0
C:\ProgramData\Notepad++                        0       0
C:\ProgramData\Oracle                           0       0
C:\ProgramData\Package Cache                    0       0
C:\ProgramData\Samsung                          0       0
C:\ProgramData\shimgen                          0       0
C:\ProgramData\Synology                         0       0
```